# How to merge polygons that have the same values in one column in Geopandas?

Tags: python, merge, geopandas

I have an shp.
with these columns:

```
ind code area
1    12  200
1    12  100
1    12  23
2    30  223
2    30  112
3    29  234
4    20  232
5    23  211
```

I want to combine each polygon with the same value in the `ind` column as one.

what I think is needed is a merge operation but how should I do it? Also will the area be summed of the polygons that will be one? for example will we have one row of `ind=1` that its `area` will be 323?

The examples with the merge are like this and involve two shp
's: how should I do with one shp?

```
# One GeoDataFrame of countries, one of Cities.
# Want to merge so we can get each city's country.
In [11]: countries.head()
Out[11]: 
                                            geometry               country
0  POLYGON ((61.21081709172574 35.65007233330923,...           Afghanistan
1  (POLYGON ((16.32652835456705 -5.87747039146621...                Angola
2  POLYGON ((20.59024743010491 41.85540416113361,...               Albania
3  POLYGON ((51.57951867046327 24.24549713795111,...  United Arab Emirates
4  (POLYGON ((-65.50000000000003 -55.199999999999...             Argentina

In [12]: cities.head()
Out[12]: 
           name                                     geometry
0  Vatican City  POINT (12.45338654497177 41.90328217996012)
1    San Marino    POINT (12.44177015780014 43.936095834768)
2         Vaduz  POINT (9.516669472907267 47.13372377429357)
3    Luxembourg  POINT (6.130002806227083 49.61166037912108)
4       Palikir  POINT (158.1499743237623 6.916643696007725)

# Execute spatial join
In [13]: cities_with_country = gpd.sjoin(cities, countries, how="inner", op='intersects')
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to take a look at the [`dissolve`](http://geopandas.org/aggregation_with_dissolve.html) method, where you can group by a certain column, take the union of the geometries for each group, and do another aggregation method on the other columns.
For example, with the countries example:

```
continents = countries.dissolve(by='continent', aggfunc='sum')
```

or in your case:

```
gdf.dissolve(by='ind', aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: I think you are correct I a have realized that it was dissolve and the output was nice but the sum u performed eluded me.Thanks for the addition. I will check it out and hope it works this part.

Comment: It says it can't happen. says type error and mentions a certain column. How is it supposed to sum the area column?it checks the numeric columns that will be dissoved and sums them?

Comment: Yes, it should take the sum for the numerical columns (and ignore the non-numerical ones). Can you provide the full traceback and example code?